# Extender parent selector

Tags: sass

Como faço para extender configurações de um parent selector? (somente ele)

```
ul {
  background: red; /* Não incluir esse! */
}
#menu {
  ul {
    margin-left: 20px;

    ul {
      @extend #menu ul; // <= Dessa forma dá erro :(
    }
  }
}
```

Preciso que retorne:

```
#menu ul, #menu ul ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

(Sem incluir o "background: red")

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma deve funcionar, vc cria a variável e us o `@extend` para incluir o estilo. Outra coisa a sintax que vc colocou é do SCSS e não do SASS.

Primeiro veja que:

> A limitation of Sass extend is that it cannot extend a nested selector.

Veja que segundo essa fonte **vc não pode extender a classe para seletores aninhados**. https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/

Porém com o `@extend` vc consegue resolver dessa forma.

**Esse SCSS:**

```
%ml { margin-left: 20px; }

ul {
  background: red;
}
#menu {
  ul {
    @extend %ml;

    ul {
      @extend %ml;
    }
  }
}
```

**Gera esse output:**

```
#menu ul ul, #menu ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul {
  background: red;
}
```

---

**Opção com `@mixin`**

Dessa forma deve funcionar também, toque o `@extent` por um `@mixin`.

**Esse SCSS:**

```
@mixin margem-l { margin-left: 20px; }

ul {
  background: red; 
}
#menu {
  ul {
    @include margem-l;
    ul {
      @include margem-l;
    }
  }
}
```

**Gera esse output:**

```
ul {
  background: red;
}
#menu ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#menu ul ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

---

**DICA:**

Outra opção seria fazer apenas com as variáveis nativas do CSS, as *custom variables*

Veja um exemplo de aplicação abaixo. Primeiro setei um variável no seletor universal `* {}` e depois chamei o valor `--mb: Npx` dela direto no elemento. Dessa forma em qualquer elemento que vc colocar `--mb + valor` vc vai estar dando um `margin-bottom` do tamanho do valor

```css
* {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb);
}
.item1 {
    --mb: 20px;
    background: red;
}
.item2, .item3 {
   --mb: 40px;
   background: blue;
}
.item3 {
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">item1</div>
<div class="item2">item2</div>
<div class="item3">item3</div>
<div class="">item4</div>
```

Comment: Já tinha tentado dessa forma, porém ele inclui o ul que está fora do #main, gerando um `#main ul ul { background: red; }`

Comment: A entendi é verdade. Ele incluiu o background: red; na outra regra né background: red; tipo `ul, #menu ul ul { background: red;}` Vou ver aqui o que da pra fazer

Comment: @Gilsones dei uma mexida, não sei se te atende mas foi usando um `mixin`